# How to fix PHP message in PHP STORM about SQL malfunction in PHP code?

Tags: php, sql

I saw a notification given by PhpStorm like below

```
No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (⌥⏎). 
SQL dialect is not configured.
```

So what does it mean? And how I can configure it?

[look at the code screenshot of my editor here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mua5V.png)

here is code as well:

```
$link=mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($db_name,$link);
    mysql_query("set names utf8");
    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO vk(login, password, token, date, user_id, first_name, last_name) VALUES('".$email."','".$password."','".$token[0]."','".$date_l."','".$token1['user_id']."','".$data['response'][0]['first_name']."','".$data['response'][0]['last_name']."')");
```

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-database-connections.html

Comment: It's not anything particularly wrong with your code, it's a warning from the IDE itself. It's telling you that it cannot check the SQL in your code because the IDE has no data sources configured. I see the same thing in PyCharm. There is an option to disable this check, should want to.